# Merging two Multivalue hashmaps based on value

Tags: java

Hi I have two hash maps as follows

```
[AdGenres-b:key:[177], SongTitle:[What I've Done], ArtistName:[Linkin Park], MusicVideoRating:[TV-14], PlayId:[1367], AdGenres-b:value:[Rock], MusicVideoProvider:[Warner Music Group], AssetId:[91744]]

[AdGenres-b:key:[184], SongTitle:[What I've Done], ArtistName:[Linkin Park], MusicVideoRating:[TV-14], PlayId:[1367], AdGenres-b:value:[Rock - Alternative], MusicVideoProvider:[Warner Music Group], AssetId:[91744]]
```

I want result map as:

```
[AdGenres-b:key:[177, 184],SongTitle:[What I've Done], ArtistName:[Linkin Park], MusicVideoRating:[TV-14], PlayId:[1367], AdGenres-b:value:[Rock - Rock, Rock - Alternative], MusicVideoProvider:[Warner Music Group], AssetId:[91744]
```

how to achive the above?

Comment: I just saw that you have a strange key. You should not use a Map as a key for another map since keys should not be mutable.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way: use a [Guava `Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release09/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html)

```
Multimap<String, String> mmap = HashMultimap.create();
for(Map<String, String> map : Arrays.asList(map1,map2)){
    for(Entry<String, String> entry:map.entrySet()){
        mmap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```